# Twitter API to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, twitter, twitterapi-python

I am a designer and I code only a little bit. I would like to know how I could use the output of the Twitter API (which I master) to use them on Unity. Which programming language would be the best? The goal is for me to do real-time creation on Unity.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can have your Twitter bot communicate with Unity by using files. So you can write in a file then read the content with C# during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The primary programming / scripting language used in Unity is C#.

There is a library for the Twitter API v1.1 called [Twity](https://github.com/toofusan/Twity). The current version of the Twitter API is v2 and you'd probably need to look for something that worked with that.